# Send data via Post Request from recycler view ( Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing app for Android , using Xamarin.

I have recycler view with  some text view and button.

I need to take data from one of text view and send it  via post request.

Here is code that I have in Adapter:

```
 public class FormAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    private readonly List<Result> form;

    public FormAdapter(List<Result> form_)
    {
        this.form = form_;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var movieViewHolder = (FormViewHolder)holder;
        movieViewHolder.OrderId.Text = "Id заказа: " + form[position].id;
        movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Text = form[position].date_created;
        movieViewHolder.DirectedByTextView.Text = "Имя: " + form[position].billing.first_name;
        movieViewHolder.ReleasedOnTextView.Text = "Телефон: " + form[position].billing.phone;
        movieViewHolder.Total.Text = " Сумма: " + form[position].total;
        movieViewHolder.Street.Text = "Улица/Дом: " + form[position].billing.address_1;
        movieViewHolder.House.Text = "Квартира: " + form[position].billing.address_2;
        movieViewHolder.Porch.Text = "Подъезд: " + form[position].billing.company;
        movieViewHolder.Floor.Text = "Этаж: " + form[position].billing.state;
        movieViewHolder.Order.Text = "Состав заказа:" + form[position].line_items[0].name;
        movieViewHolder.Done.Click += async delegate
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://api.simplegames.com.ua/");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
                string endpoint = @"post/changeStatusToCompleted.php";

                try
                {
                    HttpContent content = new StringContent(form[position].id.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        };
```

Here is screenshot of app

[image]

I have about 5 elements in recycler view. So when I tap  the button on first element I need to send ID from first element in recycler view.

I try to do it like this, but it doesn't send anything.

```
 movieViewHolder.Done.Click += async delegate
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://api.simplegames.com.ua/");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
            string endpoint = @"post/changeStatusToCompleted.php";

            try
            {
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(form[position].id.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    };
```

Where is my trouble?

Thank's for help.

**UPDATE**

I make some edit to method
Here is code

```
string result = movieViewHolder.OrderId.Text;
                Console.WriteLine("TUT" + result);
                // Console.WriteLine("TUT"+ movieViewHolder.OrderId.Text);
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://api.simplegames.com.ua/");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
                    string endpoint = @"post/changeStatusToCompleted.php";

                    try
                    {
                        HttpContent content = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the method does it even trigger?

Comment: Yes. I put breakpoint on using (HttpClietnt ......) and it trigger. Also I receive answer from server.@Cheesebaron

Comment: Could you please debug `result` to check if all necessary data are included?